# Can someone explain me what is use of FrameLayout in DrawerLayout?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-framelayout

Use of `FrameLayout` in `DrawerLayout` for android.
Can someone explain me what is use of `FrameLayout` in `DrawerLayout` ?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.tuljain.requests.MainActivity">
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout>
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/frameholder">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:id="@+id/tw3"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        </FrameLayout>
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:id="@+id/drawer"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:entries="@array/planet"
            android:divider="#d3d3d3"
            android:background="@color/drawerlayouttransparent">
        </ListView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It holds the main content that the drawer opens over.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, DrawerLayout has two components:

1. Drawer itself - acts as a remote control. Click on drawer item, and drawer will close and a new screen should open in the container area.
2. Container - acts as a container of different screens that will open when you click on drawer items. It can be any layout, not just FrameLayout..

**Example of Drawer:**

[image: Drawer]

**Example of FrameLayout: Note you cannot identify its FrameLayout**
[image]

Comment: thanks for your help but some few things are not clear to me yet. I have created a drawerLayout in activity_main.xml but when I render this it does shows nothing else than a drawerLayout. I want some view to be rendered should I write in frameLayout itself

Comment: In about frameLayout I have also added one textview but it is not showing when I run the application. It only shows the drawerLayout

Comment: Yes you can code there itself.. Usually we create a fragment and load it in this container... But initially just for checking purpose you can code for layout in the container itself.

Answer (score 0):

ref : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html

> To use a DrawerLayout, position your primary content view as the first
>   child with a width and height of

Normally Frame Layout is used for loading different views (layout for different fragments)

In the above code you have only one activity / u need Navigation drawer only in one place u cane replace Frame Layout with Liner Layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/tw3"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If you are using this navigation drawer in All/multiple pages, if you are not using Frames you need to copy past the navigation drawer code in all the xml files. So using Frame layout and fragments we an avoid that.

Comment: I have only one activity but four other fragmentations. But I am able to inflate the fragmentation when I click on navigation drawer.

Comment: Can you please have a look at the below link https://github.com/TulsiJain/Requests/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/tuljain/requests/MainActivity.java                                                                                
https://github.com/TulsiJain/Requests/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml